# Publish Outlook Add-In with dependent DLLs enclosed

Tags: vsto, office-addins

I'm writing an Outlook Add-In (VSTO) using Azure Speech service.

All work fine in Visual Studio Debug mode.

After I publish it with VS and install the Add-In (Release version). It doesn't work in Outlook.

```
        FormMainSettings.WriteLine($"Step #2: {ThisAddIn.VoiceName}, {YourSubscriptionKey}, {YourServiceRegion}");
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(YourSubscriptionKey, YourServiceRegion);
        FormMainSettings.WriteLine("Step #2.1");
```

2nd line is the first Azure Speech initializing function.
the line above it can output logs to a file.

The line below it outputs nothing.

I suspect the release version Add-In doesn't enclose necessary Azure Speech dependent DLLs. While VS Debugging mode does.

So, the Azure Speech initializing function blocks or fails or something.

Do we have a way to batch necessary external DLLs together with Add-In installer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by finding all necessary DLLs from Build path of VS, copied to Windows' SysWoW64 folder. Thanks guys.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).